# What are the benefits of a multi-coated CP filter over a regular CP filter?

Tags: filters, polarizer, optical-coating

I would like to purchase CP filters for at least 2 of my lenses. I can go with either the [lower cost regular CP filter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/22708-REG/Hoya_B77CRPL_77mm_Circular_Polarizer_Glass.html) or the [HMC Multi-Coated CP filter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/116783-REG/Hoya_A77CRPL_77mm_Circular_Polarizer_HMC.html).

THe multi-coated filter is almost double the price. Comparing the two what are the benefits of the multi-coated filter over the regular filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you gave shows "Multicoated to minimize reflection at the filter surfaces which reduces flare and ghosting.".

The layer of coating should be very thin (thickness comparabe with light wavelength in nanometers) and have very accurate thickness (measured sometimes in the size of atoms), the technology is expensive and this makes the multi-coated optics more expensive than a simple glass.

For more information you can look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_coating for instance

Comment: So the regular CP filter is not coated at all? Does it produce a lot of flare and ghosting? Is the coated filter significantly better?

Comment: It could be coated with cheaper and not so good layer or not coated at all. I do not know about this exact filter. It is better if you can just try them both. try to shoot so that there is strong direct light from side coming to lens and you should see difference.